# Geometry transformation problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, geometric-transformation

The question is :-

> ***A figure consist of five equal squares in the form of a cross .show how to divide it by two straight cuts into four equal figures which will fit together to form a square.***

Please tell what would be our approach to solve the question ,I am confused what would be our steps to proceed,even i cant guess the first step (please clearly elaborate your steps) . It is a question under the chapter ***Triangle***  of an olympiad book so something must be related to triangles definitely.

Comment: I saw the video its a nice video :) but can you tell that for a student like me how would i be able to think such a solution.. my exact question is that is there a method for these type of transformation problems?

Comment: @Ak19 In your solution figures are not congruent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hinted by the fact that if the pieces have equal area, they must have sides $\dfrac{\sqrt5}2$, which evokes the diagonal of $2\times1$ rectangles.

[image]

Comment: @AkshajBansal: do you mean that you don't see the cuts ?

Comment: @AkshajBansal: what is the diagonal of a $2\times1$ rectangle ? What is the area of the squares ?

Comment: Sorry for all that i got the question. Earlier i was thinking something else . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This image illustrates how the requisite dissection arises naturally:

[image]